# Conflicts When Bulk Uploading

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, express, knex.js

This is more of a general question, but here goes...

In my application (React, Express.js, Node, Postgres), a user is able to upload a CSV file that I then parse into JSON format, validate it, and post it to the Postgres DB. On occasion, there can be 10,000+ rows that could potentially take seconds, or a minute to fully be created on the DB and be updated.

As someone new to developing apps on this level, what happens if User A uploads a file containing 10,000 entries... and in the time that it takes to post to the DB, User B uploads the same file, or a file containing multiples of the same entries (that I validate normally to make sure there are no duplicates, etc) within the time it takes to fully post User A's data?

Can someone tell me the best way to handle this scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the conflicting row can be seen while you run conflict detection, then you will have duplicates in your database.

Triggers and there equivalent (which seems to be what you have here) are a poor way to enforce uniqueness.

If you can't enforce uniqueness with unique/exclude constraints/indexes, maybe the best solution is to use [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) to make sure only one file can be uploaded at a time.  But if there is also a way to add records via a non-bulk mechanism, that method will also lead to problems unless it too participates in the advisory locking scheme.